# Pygame. Efficient detection of line collision with sprite

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, line, collision-detection

**QUESTION**

I am currently writing a small rpg. I've managed to make a player shooting and destroy the projectile when it collides with a sprite. It works well because the player is "smart" enough to not shoot when there is a wall between him and the target.

I am currently thinking about how to move this method to my monsters. But the only way I can think of to avoid the monster shooting if there is an obstacle between the target and him is to draw a line between the two and check if the line intersects with any obstacles.

I haven't found a way of doing this efficiently. For the moment I am considering testing every single point along the line but I think that this will slow the game down significantly.

If you have any answers on how to efficiently check if a line collides with a rectangle I'd appreciate.

Thanks

**ANSWER**

Thanks to @DCA- 's comment was able to implement exactly what I was looking for. I got the [Bresenhams's](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Bresenham%27s_Line_Algorithm) line algorithm pretty much strait from the box (cpoy/pasted it in my functions.py module). I then coded in:

```
'''the range_ argument represents the maximum shooting distance at which the shooter will start firing.  and obstacles is a list of obstacles, shooter and target are both pygame Sprites'''
def in_sight(shooter, target, range_, obstacles):
    line_of_sight = get_line(shooter.rect.center, target.rect.center)
    zone = shooter.rect.inflate(range_,range_)
    obstacles_list = [rectangle.rect for rectangle in obstacles] #to support indexing
    obstacles_in_sight = zone.collidelistall(obstacles_list)
    for x in range(1,len(line_of_sight),5):
        for obs_index in obstacles_in_sight:
            if obstacles_list[obs_index].collidepoint(line_of_sight[x]):
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a line of sight algorithm.

Look into [Bresenhams's](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Bresenham%27s_Line_Algorithm) line algorithm or other such resourses as a starting point.

This is a common algorithm used in 2d rogue-like's and rpg's.

I can't vouch for the efficiency of the algorithm or it's speed when implemented in python but hopefully this gives you a point in the right direction.

Another useful algorithm may be Raycasting. There are many python implementation around and won't be hard to find.

Hope this helps.